# Laravel localization with Route::group, prefix and namespace

Tags: php, laravel, localization

"You may also change the active language at runtime using the setLocale method on the App facade:"
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization#introduction

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

How do we do that with $locale if we have something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{id}/{locale}', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function( $locale ) {
    // this does not work.
    App::setLocale( $locale );

    // this does work.
    App::setLocale( Request::segment( 3 ) );

    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['except' => [
        'show'
    ]]);

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: Issue is with the number of route parameters. Refer my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with route parameters not with localization

Since you expect two params for the route you should pass two params for the closure.

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) { 
    // 
});
```

In your example

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{id}/{locale}', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function( $id, $locale ) { 
    // this does not work.
    App::setLocale( $locale ); 
    // this does work.
    App::setLocale( Request::segment( 3 ) );
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['except' => [ 'show' ]]);
});
```

Refer [route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters) for more info

Comment: I had already tried this. Missing argument 2 for App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::{closure}()

Answer (score 0):

Please note - `Route::group` callback executes on any request (even not for your prefix!). `Route::group` is not similar to `Route::get/post/match`, it is like a helper for internal get/post/match calls.

`App::setLocale( $locale );` does not work because `Laravel` passes only instance of `Illuminate\Routing\Router` into group's callback. On this stage `locale` prefix has not been extracted and even URL has not been processed.

`App::setLocale( Request::segment( 3 ) );` will be executed for 'one/two/three' with 'three' as a locale.

Your example should be:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{id}/{locale}', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    // test a locale
    Route::get('test', function($locale){ echo $locale; });

    // ProductController::index($locale)
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['except' => [
        'show'
    ]]);
});
```

So, just update your ProductController and add $locale as a parameter.

**Alternative:** if you want setLocale in one place update your routes:

```
// set locale for '/admin/anything/[en|fr|ru|jp]/anything' only
if (Request::segment(1) === 'admin' && in_array(Request::segment(3), ['en', 'fr', 'ru', 'jp'])) {
    App::setLocale(Request::segment(3));
} else {
    // set default / fallback locale
    App::setLocale('en');
}

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/{id}/{locale}', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['except' => [
        'show'
    ]]);
});
```